# Binding IP Addresses

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I'm rewriting some C++ code to C#. The code I'm refactoring uses [AddIPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in C++ but I cannot find a way to do the same in C#. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to call the method directly. [This page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.addipaddress) has the details (and a sample) of how you can go about that.

The basic idea is to create a C# method that corresponds to the native method by declaring it as `extern`, and decorating it with the `DllImport` attribute:

```
DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", EntryPoint = "AddIPAddress", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern UInt32 AddIPAddress(UInt32 Address, UInt32 IpMaskint, int IfIndex, out int NTEContext, out int NTEInstance);
```

Comment: The last two parameters should _not_ be `IntPtr`, or the code will only work on 32-bit systems (they should be `uint` or `int` instead).

Comment: @ildjarn I haven't used the method before; this was more of an answer about the existence of p/invoke than the how to call the method. That said, the final two parameters to `AddIPAddress` are `PULONG`; wouldn't that mean that they would be 32 bits on 32-bit systems and 64 bits on 64-bit systems?

Comment: @dlev : No, in Visual C++, `int` and `long` are always 32-bit types (`long long` is 64-bits and `PULONG_PTR` would be the `UIntPtr` equivalent).

Comment: @ildjarn While `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) == 4`, doesn't `sizeof(long*)` depend on the architecture, just as `IntPtr.Size` does? (Seriously, I haven't done C++ in a long time, so I'm asking out of curiosity, not obstinacy :) )

Comment: @dlev : `out` takes care of that; the size of the underlying object (i.e. the object being pointed to) is the concern here.